# Is there a homeomorphism between the sets of Schur stable and Hurwitz stable matrices in companion forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, matrix-analysis, path-connected

This is a cross-post to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952997/is-there-a-homeomorphism-between-the-sets-of-schur-stable-and-hurwitz-stable-mat) I asked at MSE.

---

The set of Schur stable matrices is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal S = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb R): \rho(A) < 1\},
\end{align*}
where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes the spectral radius of a matrix and the set of Hurwitz stable matrices is 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal H = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb R): \max_{i=1, \dots, n} \text{Re}(\lambda_i(A)) < 0\},
\end{align*}
i.e., matrices with eigenvalues lying on the open left half plane.
Let $\mathcal C$ denote all matrices in [companion form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Let $\hat{\mathcal S} = \mathcal S \cap \mathcal C$ and $\hat{\mathcal H} = \mathcal H \cap \mathcal C$. Now I would like to determine whether there is a homeomorphism between the sets $\hat {\mathcal S}$ and $\hat{\mathcal H}$. Let us exclude the trivial case $n=1$.

If we consider the sets $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal H$ only, there is a diffeomorphism $f: \mathcal S \to \mathcal H$ given by
\begin{align*}
A \mapsto (A-I)^{-1}(A+I).
\end{align*}
But apparently this doesn't work for $\hat {\mathcal S}$ and $\hat{\mathcal H}$ since the inversion and multiplication will not necessarily yield a matrix in companion form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you're asking if there is a homeomorphism between the monic real polynomials of degree $n$ with roots in the open unit disk and those with roots in the left half plane.  Just take $$\prod_{j=1}^n (x - \alpha_j) \mapsto \prod_{j=1}^n \left(x - \frac{\alpha_j+1}{\alpha_j - 1}\right)$$
This should work because the multiset of roots of a polynomial is a continuous function of the coefficients.